# How to Avoid Firefox Displaying a Notification Bar when a PDF is in a Div with CSS Property Display:None?

Tags: css, firefox, pdf

I have a site where the user views PDFs one at a time by choosing from a drop-down.

Apparently if you Display:None a Div that contains a PDF, Firefox displays a notification bar that reads "This PDF document might not be displayed correctly." The PDFs do display correctly, however!

```
<div style="display:none">
    <object data="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf"> </object>
</div>
```

All divs are Display:None by default. The result is the same even if Display:None is in the object tag.

If I use Visibility:Hidden instead of Display:None, Firefox does not display the notification bar; however I need to use Display:None so that the Divs stay overlapped (Visibility:Hidden prevents the elements from displaying but the elements still take up space in the layout, which isn't an option for me).

Anyone know how to prevent/avoid Firefox displaying a notification bar when a PDF is in a Div with Display:None?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the PDF plug-in in the current builds of Firefox have a bug that produces this error for many PDFs. It's very possible the bug(s) could be the reason why you're getting that notification bar under certain circumstances.

Here are some Mozilla support forums related to the problem:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952574
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/954073

They refer to v. 19, but I'm on Firefox v. 24 and still see these errors. If you have a public link you can share, I'll be happy to verify on my side.

One more thing: if you view the PDF by itself in Firefox, does the notification bar appear?